# Testing React frontend with laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, reactjs, testing, form-submit, laravel-dusk

I am trying to run tests for submitting a form in my react front end using laravel dusk. the form doesn't gets submitted.

this is the test I am running.

```
public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email'     => 'testuser@email.com',
            'password'  => bcrypt('password')
        ]);

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->type('username', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'password')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertSee('Dashboard');
        });
}
```

Is there something wrong with my test?

can anyone help me ??

Comment: sure. I can provide you the code.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code @Troyer

Comment: sup! hey phpunit is to test code written in PHP not in javascript or react. Id recomment you write your tests in Jest -> https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html. Best of luck

Comment: ok...So can I use jest for browser testing?? @HBensiali

Comment: for testing reactjs. Jest ships with react as the default testing like phpunit does for laravel. Its very nice to use. really no different from phpunit. Each component should be isolated & tested before introduced to the rest of your code.

Comment: testing code is laborious, but long run..... it would serve you better to do so. Write your code in your tests, get them passing then push them into your project

Comment: can I use jest for end-to-end testing??? just as laravel dusk does by opening a browser. @HBensiali

Comment: mmmm if you need something a little more granular, I'd recommend Nightmarejs -> http://www.nightmarejs.org/. Jest is straight out the box testing. Jest for me does the job.

Comment: Ok...so you test your react ui using jest?? Well i have heard of nightmarejs...any tutorials you know about using it @HBensiali

Comment: yep jest is basic, but I thinking I'll be switching to nightmare soon. Same thing, just more features under the hood. Checkout https://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/writing-end-to-end-tests-with-nightmare-js & the git https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare